# Can't access root from remote desktop when root is already logged in

Tags: remote-desktop, performance, remote-control, root

I can access all users even root using remote desktop from Windows to Mac with the TightVNC Viewer.

The problem is trying to access root from my PC when someone in Mac already logged in root, then TightVNC Viewer freezes and I have to close it.

This only happen to me since Mac OS X 10.8, 10.9, and 10.10.

I gave permissions to every single user.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by: "someone is already logged **in** root"?

Comment: @danielAzuelos well, in my Mac computer, i log in root, then i want to access with my PC (Windows computer) using TightVNC Viewer to my Mac, and i can do it. But when i try to log in root, the TightVNC Viewer freezes and this is not happening when i try to access other user that is not root.

Comment: "root" as user with uid 0 (the unix-level root user which needs to be enabled first) or Administrator?

Comment: @patrix the one who needs to be enabled first

Comment: When you log in as root (UID = 0), do you mean through the graphical interface to start an interactive session, or through VNC, or through `ssh` or any other protocol?

Comment: @danielAzuelos first i log in as root in Mac computer, then i want to log in root at the same time through TightVNC with my PC computer.

Comment: Did you look at `/var/log/authd.log` and `/var/log/accountpolicy.log` on the target Mac to check for any related permission error?

Comment: @danielAzuelos I can access root terminal with ssh, but i need graphical interface, and when i try to connect using TightVNC, i get the login screen where i can write the user (root) and password, then i put them, and when is trying to join the sesion, TightVNC freezes

Comment: @danielAzuelos it says everything is allright, both logs: Apr 23 17:09:24 (45.2) AuthenticationAllowed completed: record "root", result: Success (0).